# Remove flags (-fpermissive) from Makefile (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, projects-and-solutions

I have Googled everywhere, and have not managed to figure out how to remove the `-fpermissive` flag from my Qt-generated Makefiles. The `-fpermissive` flag is defaultly there, even if I do `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= -fpermissive` in my Qt project file, attempting to remove it. Here is my Makefile where the flags are:

```
CFLAGS        = -fpermissive -finline-functions -Wno-long-long -g -Wall $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -fpermissive -finline-functions -Wno-long-long -g -fexceptions -mthreads -frtti -Wall $(DEFINES)
```

How can I remove these?

Answer (score 1):

My QtCreator-generated makefiles don't have *-fpermissive* anywhere in them, at least as far as I can Ctrl+F.
Check your project's Build Settings, and make sure you don't have *-fpermissive* in there as command-line arguments.

[image]

This is the the same two lines in my QMake-generated makefile:

```
CFLAGS        = -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -O2 -Wall -Wextra $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -O2 -std=c++11 -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads $(DEFINES)
```

My makefiles also references a file called 'qmake.conf', which for me is located at:
**C:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/mingw47_32/mkspecs/win32-g++/qmake.conf**

It looks like the qmake.conf is used to help generate makefiles for different compilers and platforms, and can add arguments to your makefile.